# Return all columns excluding rows with a duplicateID in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

I have an interesting issue.

I inherited a sloppy database with a table that has duplicate rows.  However, they are not exact duplicates due to one column(a text column).

Here is an example:

```
TestID            TestDescription                                               Cost
115893hc127aaq    Etiology    • Understand the causes of acute pancreatitis     $10
115893hc127aaq    Etiology • Understand   the causes of acute pancreatitis      $10
115893hc127aaq    Etiology  • Understand the causes of acute   pancreatitis     $10
```

You can see that all the data except the 'TestDescription' is identical.

There are 1000's of rows like this where there might be 2 or 3 duplicate rows with minor spacing or spelling issues in 'TestDescription'

Because of this, using DISTINCT won't work.

I want to SELECT all rows but only get one row for each TestID...lets say the first one, then ignore the rest.

I tried SELECT DISTINCT *

But I can't do this using DISTINCT because TestDescription contains minor differences between rows.

SELECT DISTINCT TestID works, but that only returns TestID and I need to see all columns.

Is there a way of doing this in Sql Server 2012?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by testid order by (select null)) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

This assumes that you want one row per `testid`, as your question suggests.

You did not tell which column you want to use to break the ties, and I am unsure there is actually one, so I odered by `(select null)`. This is not a deterministic `order by` clause, so consequent executions of the query might not always select the same row from a given duplicate group.

Comment: I only care about the TestID being distinct.  In the table, the TestDescriptions might be different in regards to spacing, but they all convey the same meaning to someone seeing it.  Thanks!

Comment: This *almost* works but it adds a column called, 'rn'.  And when I try to do an INSERT to a backup table using the query I get a `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`  Is there a way to ignore the 'rn' column when doing an INSERT?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: just replace `select *` with the list of columns of the table.